# vsftpd - Конфиг не выполняет своих обязанностей

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, vsftpd

Мой конфиг не должен пускать юзеров которые не находятся в userlist'е но он их пускает, он не должен пускать их дальше своей домашней директории, но они успешно могут заходить в любые каталоги.
Вот мой конфиг: https://pastebin.com/EpWYhiMf
Уже второй день не могу ничего с этим сделать, надеюсь на вашу помощь